# Can a "MVC 5 route" be used as a path in an error element in system.webServer httpErrors section in web.config?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

Can a "MVC 5 route" be used as a `path` in an `error` element in `system.webServer` `httpErrors` section in web.config?

```
<configuration>
...other config stuff...
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="/Error/NotFound" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Yes, the responseMode setting is important to ensure the correct routing kicks in during error conditions. What results are you seeing?

Comment: So ExecuteURL is not just for .aspx pages? MSDN/IIS docs are not very clear about that. ExecuteURL Serves dynamic content (for example, an .asp file) specified in the path attribute for the custom error. If responseMode is set to ExecuteURL, the path value has to be a server relative URL. The numeric value is 1

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. With `responseMode="ExecuteURL"` IIS internally "redirects" (sends a request for the given URL) and writes the result to the response.

You might also want to set the `existingResponse` attribute in `httpErrors` to `Replace`.

Be aware that:

> For architectural reasons, IIS 7.0 can only execute the URL if it is located in the same Application Pool. Use the redirect feature to execute a Custom Error in a different Application Pool.